# Use string as argument for GetValue()

Tags: c#, xml

I have a class `Player`, and an instance of that class called `player`. Inside that class, I have an auto-property called `Name`.

I need to access the property `Name` from the instance. I already know of other ways to do this, but because of what I want this program to do, I need to do it via:

```
var type= Type.GetType("GameSpace.Player")
var property = type.GetProperty("Name");
var propVal = property.GetValue(player);

Console.WriteLine(propVal);
```

This code works perfectly fine. The issue here is that sometimes, I will need to change the name of the instance, which in this case is player. I thought of making a string to hold the name of the instance.

```
string instanceName = "player";
enter code here
var type= Type.GetType("GameSpace.Player")
var property = type.GetProperty("Name");
var propVal = property.GetValue(instanceName);

Console.WriteLine(propVal);
```

But this doesn't working, throwing the error that GetValue doesn't have an overload that allows a string value.

Is there a way to accomplish what I am asking for. I know that I can simply do `Console.WriteLine(player.Name)`, but in this case that is not an options, mostly because the arguments (name of instance) are stored in an XML file.

**EDIT 1:**
Error Message:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `PropertyInfo.GetValue`?

Comment: I did @JonSkeet, and it says it only supports objects[] as an arguement value.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Note that there are more overloads for more recent versions of .NET - if you target .NET 4.5, I think this *should* already compile. Which version of .NET are you targeting? If you've only got the two-parameter version available, then you'll need to pass two arguments - look at the documentation for what you want to pass as the second argument.

Comment: I see that it can hold an object as an arguement, @JonSkeet, but when I try the code in my question it doesn't work as intended. I am not sure why

Comment: Are you sure this is failing to *compile* at all, by the way? If the first version compiles, I'd expect the second version to compile (but not run). Please show the *exact* error message. "Doesn't work as intended" is not a good description of what you're seeing.

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen because it expects an instance not an instance name.

Comment: The issue that comes up occurs not in compiling, but when the program ends up running that code. Screenshot of issue is on the question, @JonSkeet

Comment: Right, that was *very* unclear from your description - the error doesn't say anything about "GetValue doesn't have an overload that allows a string value" does it? Also, you don't need a screenshot - just a copy of the message and stack trace would be better.

Comment: @JonSkeet, true, sorry about that. Is there still a way of making what I want work, to allow a string to reference the instance I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instances don't have names, generally. (You can create a class with a `Name` property, but that's nothing the framework is going to care about.) The value you have to pass to `PropertyInfo.GetValue` is a reference to the object whose property you want to fetch. Passing a name makes no sense to the framework. (Apart from anything else, it has no context - there could be *lots* of variables with that name in all kinds of places.)

*Variables* have names. If the name you've got refers to a local variable, you're out of luck - but if the name you've got refers to a field, you can get at that field via reflection. Get the right `FieldInfo`, then get the value of that.

However, it may well be better just to have a `Dictionary<string, object>` mapping the names you might run into in the XML file into the appropriate objects you want to fetch properties for. Alternatively, you could have a `switch` statement to get at the right value - it really depends on the context.

Generally, tying your class implementation (field names) to an XML file is a bad idea, IMO.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Dictionary, but does it work like if the string I have an XML is in the dictionary, it spits out an object? Like, if you looked for a word in a dictionary, it spits out a definition?

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen: Well, you need to populate it, but yes - it's a mapping from keys to values. If you're new to C# and .NET (which I'm assuming you are, as `Dictionary` is a very commonly-used type) I'd strongly advise you to learn the core types of the platform - particularly the collection classes - before you start messing with reflection, which is *relatively* advanced.

Comment: So I could have all possible options stored in the string, then simply allow the dictionary to spit out the needed object. Then, I could use object in the GetValue(), right?

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen: I don't know what you mean by "all possible options stored in the string" - you'd store them in the *dictionary*. I suggest at this point you find a good tutorial on .NET collections, then try it.

Comment: I meant, in the string section of the dictionary?

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen: There aren't "sections" in a dictionary. There are keys and values. *Please* go and read a tutorial, try it, and ask for more details if it doesn't work. Stack Overflow isn't meant to be an interactive debugging session.